# Outlook 2016 hangs when opening emails with some SharePoint links

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sharepoint

I get emails from time to time that have links to SharePoint docs. I noticed that in some cases, I would get the "contacting the server" window as shown [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/why-am-i-getting-the-message-contacting-the-server-for-information-973c8d98-4d22-49b5-bc66-0d9d87783f99) which would not go away for 10-15 minutes even if I click Cancel. Outlook would be unusable until the window goes away. It appears that this happens only when the link is to a Word doc (as opposed to Excel, for example). None of the solutions described in the Microsoft page linked above helped.

Is there a way to stop this?

I am using Office 2016 on a Win 10 machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the perspective of the Outlook client, it is suggested to set your Automatic Download settings a bit more stricter and see if the issue has any difference. Please check the information in this article:[Contacting Server for Information](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/720).